# Objects created with dangerous SET Options in SSISDB

Tags: sql-server, sp-blitz

I recently updated my Brent Ozar first responder kit and ran sp_Blitz and it returned an alert:

> The [SSISDB] database has 107 objects that were created with dangerous
> ANSI_NULL or QUOTED_IDENTIFIER options. These objects can break when
> using filtered indexes, indexed views and other advanced SQL features.

These appear to be objects in the 'catalog' and 'internal' schemas that I believe are built during the install and not something one of our developer have created. Do I need to be concerned and take any action on these?

Comment: SSISDB is managed by Microsoft. Does this query return any rows? `USE SSISDB; SELECT  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) AS SchemaName
 ,type_desc AS ObjectType
 ,OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'ExecIsQuotedIdentOn') AS ExecIsQuotedIdentOn
 ,OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'ExecIsAnsiNullsOn') AS ExecIsAnsiNullsOn
 ,OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'IsAnsiNullsOn') AS IsAnsiNullsOn
FROM SSISDB.sys.objects
WHERE 
 OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'ExecIsAnsiNullsOn') = 0
 OR OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'ExecIsAnsiNullsOn') = 0
 OR OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'IsAnsiNullsOn') = 0;`

Comment: FWIW, all objects have the settings ON in the SSISDB I checked.

Comment: @DanGuzman When I run that query it returns 107 rows with a 0 populated in every column of every row. I looked at the stored procedure for catalog.update_master_address (just selected one at random) and it includes 'SET ANSI_NULLS OFF' and 'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF'.

Comment: FWIW, I just created a new SSISDB catalog via SSMS and and all options are ON. SSMS created the database with a restore from file `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DTS\Binn\SSISDBBackup.bak` so the set options in my case are from the database provided by Microsoft setup. There may be some history behind your SSISDB like upgrades that resulted on the options OFF but I wouldn't worry about it unless you've  recreated the objects manually without the  correct SET options.